# Redux persist resetting to initial state issue(version 4)?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist

i am new in react native. 
 i have some forms and i am saving data to redux state. 
 i am facing a strange issue that some time data changing to initial state when i try to reload the app.
 Let me know any solution for this issue.`[![enter code here][1]][1]`

[![state][1]][1]

```
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
    return createStore(
        reducers,
        preloadedState,
        compose(
            autoRehydrate(),
            applyMiddleware(
                ReduxThunk,
                loggerMiddleware
            )
        )
    )


}
```

App.js

```
const store = configureStore();
const persistor =persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage,blacklist :["mobileNumber"]})
export default class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={store} persistor={persistor}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Router />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to share your store creation code if you hope any help on this.

Comment: @jevakallio updated my code

Comment: Which values do you want to persist? Use `whitelist: ["valuesToPersist'"]` for storing, not blacklist.